# When to ask for Health kit permission request

Tags: ios, healthkit

I am working on a health habit app. 
I was wondering, should we ask for Heath-kit access grant with consent ONLY after users sign up?  Or it is not related?

Comment: Get user permission before navigating to Health dashboard ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Your app should request authorization after the user sets up the feature that would depend on accessing their data. That way, the user is not forced to decide whether the app should have access before the app has explained how it is going to use the data.